# Rendering images from REST response on localhost

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to run a REST API on one port (8000) using django and consuming that API in an App running on port 9000 again using django.

My REST response is having an image field, now the problem is that i can not provide my desktop path in upload_to option in my API models and if i am giving the absolute path of API project in my App project index. Html,  i get a browser error as "Not allowed to load resources from local path"

So i am having to create media folders with same name in both API and App projects  and keeping image files in both and using only the file path from the REST response and rendering the image from App project itself.

Is there any way i can get away with this and consume the image from the Rest response only?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert image to base64 in server side then send those base64 string as response  . Then consume this base64 string as response in calling api. Then use it accordingly either save in filesysyem or in database . But make sure to converse base 64 image string to bytes.